# Healing dust and scratch marks in scanned photos in post-processing

Tags: dust

I borrowed a Coolscan V ED (LS-50 ED) scanner and scanned some old negatives as .NEF files. However, I didn't turn on all the Scan Image Enhancer / Digital ICE features, so a lot of them have quite a few dust and scratch marks.

I though I can just remove them in post-processing, which may have been a mistake as I didn't think it all through.

So what should I use now to fix those dust and scratch marks?

I have LightRoom but I suspect that won't be the best tool for these particular problems.

Any advice on which tool, preferably not terribly expensive, to use? Preferably one that can do some automatic processing in batch mode.

Comment: |Do you have anything other than Lightroom? (PS?)

Comment: Not at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about trying the Kodak tool. It was perfect for that : http://alphatracks.com/archives/134

Comment: I have now used the tool with good results. Thanks again for recommending it.

Comment: @JohnMurdoch : you're welcome